# Make DataRepeater bound to List(Of Object) update?

Tags: vb.net, binding, datarepeater

What is the correct way to bind a List(Of Object) to a DataRepeater? Can you provide example code for this?

I have been racking my brains on this and while I can get an already filled list to show in the repeater, subsequent changes to the list have no effect on the DataRepeater.

Ultimately I hope to use this to bind to a dictionary, if that is possible, but I cannot even get the basics working here.

The data repeater is added on the form design surface, with 3 labels and a progress bar in the ItemTemplate. The code I have attempted (where DutData is the DataRepeater) to setup the list and repeater is then:

```
Public Class BurnIn
    Public Shared currentDuts As New Dictionary(Of UInteger, DeviceUnderTest)   ' Collection of all current DUTs.
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim testTemp As Boolean = False
    Dim testList As New List(Of DeviceUnderTest)

    Private Sub BurnIn_Load() Handles Me.Load
        '...
        ' Add two items to the dictionary and populate them
        currentDuts.Add(0, New DeviceUnderTest(Me.user, 0))
        currentDuts.Item(0).RackBay = "012345678901"
        currentDuts.Item(0).AssemblySerial = "123456789"
        currentDuts.Item(0).SetProgram(1, "Program1")

        currentDuts.Add(currentDuts.Count, New DeviceUnderTest(Me.user, 1))
        currentDuts.Item(1).RackBay = "109876543210"
        currentDuts.Item(1).AssemblySerial = "1319A5126"
        currentDuts.Item(1).SetProgram(1, "Program1")
        ' Copy the items to the test list.
        testList.Add(currentDuts.Item(0))
        testList.Add(currentDuts.Item(1))
        testTemp = True

        ' Setup the binding source, data source and data bindings.
        bs.DataSource = testList
        LocationLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "RackBay")
        DutLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "AssemblySerial")
        ProgramLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Program")
        DutProgress.DataBindings.Add("Value", bs, "Progress")
        DutData.DataSource = testList
        '...
        Me.Show()
    End Sub
```

Then to test adding or removing list items:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
        If testTemp = False Then
            ' Add an item to the dictionary and populate it.
            currentDuts.Add(currentDuts.Count, New DeviceUnderTest(Me.user, 1))
            currentDuts.Item(1).RackBay = "109876543210"
            currentDuts.Item(1).AssemblySerial = "1319A5126"
            currentDuts.Item(1).SetProgram(1, "Program1")
            ' Copy the item to the test list.
            testList.Add(currentDuts.Item(1))
            testTemp = True
        Else
            ' Remove the item from the dictionary and the list.
            currentDuts.Remove(1)
            testList.Remove(testList.Item(1))
            testTemp = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to replace your List with a BindingList

```
Dim testList As New BindingList(Of DeviceUnderTest)
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works. However is there any other way? For example if I wanted to bind to a collection instead does BindingCollection provide the equivalent functionality?

Comment: Yes the BindingX objects implement the interfaces needed for successful binding InotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged IIRC